# Is the radical of the product of ideals equal to the product of the radicals? $ \sqrt{I}\cdot \sqrt{J} = \sqrt{I \cdot J} $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

> **Question:** Is this formula true: $$ \sqrt{I}\cdot \sqrt{J} = \sqrt{I \cdot J} $$ for ideals $I,J$ in a commutative Noetherian ring?

The only result I could find on the internet was [this unanswered post on another website](http://mathhelpforum.com/advanced-algebra/227063-radical-product-ideals-vs-product-radicals-ideals.html).

I know that $$\sqrt{I \cdot J} = \sqrt{I \cap J} = \sqrt{I} \cap \sqrt{J}$$ see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290229/explaining-the-product-of-two-ideals/290484#290484), and [here (Lemma 1.7)](http://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/commalg-2013/chapter-1.pdf). I want to combine the answer to my question (assuming it is positive), with the aforementioned true result, and the Strong Nullstellensatz, to prove that $Z(I_1) \cup Z(I_2) = Z(I_1 \cdot I_2) = Z(I_1 \cap I_2)$ over an [algebraically closed field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318149/product-of-ideals-corresponding-to-vanishing-of-points-is-equal-to-their-interse).

[The original motivation for everything](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1965167/how-to-prove-every-radical-ideal-is-the-finite-intersection-of-prime-ideals).

Comment: Let $I, J = (x)$ as ideals of $k[x]$ where $k$ is field.

Comment: In $\Bbb Z$, for a prime $p$, we have that $(p)\cdot (p)=(p^2)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $R$ be a noetherian domain which is not a field and $\mathfrak m$ a maximal ideal. By using Nakayama's lemma on the extended ideals in the ring $R_{\mathfrak m} $, we have $\mathfrak m\ne\mathfrak m^2$, therefore $$\sqrt{\mathfrak m}\cdot\sqrt{\mathfrak m}=\mathfrak m\cdot\mathfrak m=\mathfrak m^2\ne \sqrt{\mathfrak m^2}=\mathfrak m$$